# Is it commendable to break the fast after a precautionary few mintutes?

Tags: sawm, time

Some people break their fast approximately one or two minutes after the precaution timetable. Is it a commendable act?

What about the injunction against hastening in breaking the fast?

Comment: @ARINA, it could be a significant question and /i assume it would be good if Muslim observe it (breaking the fast with delay) as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

One should break one's fast once one confirms (through listening to adhān, or through other means) that the time for maghrib has started. Delaying it by 1-2 minutes, or any other arbitrary number of minutes for that matter, is a custom that was not followed by the Prophet ﷺ. In fact, he commanded us to do the opposite:

> #### عَنْ سَهْلِ بْنِ سَعْدٍ أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ ﷺ قَالَ:‏ لاَ يَزَالُ النَّاسُ بِخَيْرٍ مَا عَجَّلُوا الْفِطْرَ
>
> Narrated Sahl bin Sa'd: Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "The people will remain on the right path as long as they hasten the breaking of the fast."
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhari 1957](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/30/64)

This hadith was also documented in [Sunan Ibn Majah 7/1768](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/1317690) with an addition for this command from the Prophet ﷺ that the Jews used to delay their breaking of their fasting, and in [Sunan Abi Dawud 14/41](https://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/14/41) with an addition that both the Jews and Christians used to do so.